# Какое здесь сказуемое?

Tags: сказуемые

Волк считается стайным животным.
Считается животным или просто считается.

Comment: "Считается стайным", либо "считается стайным животным", смотря было ли упоминание, что волк это животное до этого.

Comment: @Буратино: _"**Считается стайным**", либо "считается стайным животным"_… === «Считается **стайным**» — однозначно нет. Наверное, Вы хотели написать «считается **животным**»❓

Comment: @Слава Волки и львы живут в группах. Волки считаются стайными... / Волк считается животным - ну это вообще какая-то очевидность, вроде полено состоит и древесины. И скорее всего речевая ошибка, потому что волк не считается животным, он определяется как животное. Считается - это более условное значение. Волки могут выживать и без стаи к тому же, а выживать без того что они живые они не могут, волк не считающийся животным - это чучело волка или волк на картинке, условный волк.

Comment: @Буратино, если Вы хотите сказуемым считать словосочетание «считается  стайным», то тогда каким членом предложения Вы предложите считать слово «животным»? И от какого члена предложения и какой вопрос к этому слову можно задать?

Comment: @Слава дополнением считается стайным кем? - животным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Волк считается стайным животным.***

Это **составное именное сказуемое**,  состоит из двух
компонентов: [связка] + [именная часть]
Блажен, кто смолоду был молод,.. (П.): был —- глагол-связка,
молод — именная часть.

**Связка** выражает значения **времени и модальности** (предикативность), а также различные модально-оценочные значения (наличия, становления, проявления, обнаружения признака).

**Типы СВЯЗОК:**

**1) незнаменательная:** глагол быть (в наст, времени имеет нулевую форму);

**2) полузнаменательная:** ***являться,*** делаться, стать, становиться, казаться, оказаться, показаться, **СЧИТАТЬСЯ,** слыть, называться, превратиться в, оставаться, притвориться, получаться, выходить и др.; в качестве полузнаменательных связок употребляются также **описательные обороты** иметь (носить) характер; приобретать вид (характер, положение);

**3) знаменательная** — глаголы движения и положения (прийти,
наступить, стоять и др.): пришел (усталый).

**Именная часть** может быть  выражена **нечленимым словосочетанием:** Он 0 хороший человек; Она
девушка с характером / с голубыми глазами; Он  один из старейших сотрудников; Камень был необычного цвета / огромного размера I редкого сорта; Мы были в ужасном состоянии / трудном положении I прекрасном настроении;

Но это нужно **отдельно доказывать.**  См. комментарий @Буратино

В данном случае возможно **контекстуально** неразложимое сочетание ***"стайное животное"***, но такой вывод можно сделать только по содержанию **всего текста** (не по отдельному предложению).

Материал дан **по [учебнику](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf), стр. 72**

Comment: То есть "считается стайным животным" должно быть? А может быть "считается животным"? Мне надо делать разбор согласно школьной методике.Зачтут ли такой вариант?

Comment: Смотря какая школа.  Неразложимые сочетания изучают не все.  Если не было такой темы, то, может, лучше остановиться просто на животном. Ведь здесь контекстуальность надо учитывать, это вообще сложная тема.  Вот такой вам надо сделать выбор)  С другой стороны, к примеру, "хороший человек"  вообще считается образцом неразложимого сочетания, это могут и в школе изучать. Со стайным животным сложнее, но можно рискнуть.  Только надо как-то объяснить. Например, животное – отвлеченное слово, ему нужен распространитель в виде определения. Поэтому входит в сказуемое.

Comment: Возьмем такое предложение:  Многие  животные живут стаями, волк тоже стайное животное. Здесь стайное – это определение, в сказуемое оно не входит, потому что слово "животное уже есть в контексте.

Comment: Sharon, я ваш ответ отметил, а вот последний комментарий не понял. "Волк тоже стайное животное". Здесь что, сказуемое только "животное"?

Comment: Да, я так считаю.  Что это животное уже сказано, а теперь мы определяем, какое животное. Вы не согласны?

Comment: Я не не согласен. Просто странно как-то: *Волк – животное*, тем более что о животных уже упоминалось. И это вроде бы противоречит вашему ответу, где упор делается на нечленимые сочетания.

Comment: У меня контекстуально нечленимое сочетание.  Мы же можем сказать, к примеру: Волк – это животное,  и у него соответствующие инстинкты.  В каждом тексте свое решение.  Или: Животные бывают стайные и не ставные, волк  – стайное животное.

Comment: Ну так вы привели контекст: *Многие животные живут стаями* (и в последнем комментарии тоже). Определяется волк: он не просто животное, а именно стайное. Здесь мне видится в качестве сказуемого неразложимое словосочетание.

Comment: Я так не считаю, логическое ударение на определении.  Буратино вроде так же говорит в комментарии.

Comment: Очень мутная это тема... Кто как видит, короче.

Comment: Мутная, да. Поэтому школьникам лучше не вспоминать об этом. К тому же трудно вообще представить текст, где это будет  неразложимое сочетание. Больше похоже на  абстракцию.  А если серьезно изучать тему, то не получится, кто как видит. Спросят по все строгости)

Answer (score 2):

Здесь составное именное сказуемое: "считается стайным животным". Ни одно слово здесь нельзя убрать без искажения смысла предложения. Автор не пытается сказать, что волка причисляют к животным. Он говорит, что волк относится к категории стайных животных.

Comment: СГС?  Там структура такая:  связка + инфинитив.  А инфинитива нет.